# Error when running liquibase-maven-plugin install

Tags: java, maven, liquibase

I am trying to run liquibase-maven-plugin install but I am getting the following error

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project liquibase-maven-plugin: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:maven-plugin:4.3.2-local-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.liquibase:liquibase-core:jar:4.3.2-local-SNAPSHOT, org.liquibase:liquibase-core:jar:tests:4.3.2-local-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.liquibase:liquibase-core:jar:4.3.2-local-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

Also when I try liquibase-maven-plugin compile I get this error

```
[WARNING] The POM for org.liquibase:liquibase-core:jar:4.3.2-local-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for org.liquibase:liquibase-core:jar:tests:4.3.2-local-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  3.302 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2021-03-26T14:43:32Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project liquibase-maven-plugin: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:maven-plugin:4.3.2-local-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact org.liquibase:liquibase-core:jar:4.3.2-local-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException

Process finished with exit code 1
```

### pom File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
        <artifactId>liquibase-base-module</artifactId>
        <version>${liquibase.version}</version>
        <relativePath>../base-module.pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <packaging>maven-plugin</packaging>
    <description>A Maven plugin wraps up some of the functionality of Liquibase</description>

    <properties>
        <targetMavenVersion>3.3.9</targetMavenVersion>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
            <version>${targetMavenVersion}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-core</artifactId>
            <version>${targetMavenVersion}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-artifact</artifactId>
            <version>${targetMavenVersion}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compat</artifactId>
            <version>${targetMavenVersion}</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-testing</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin-testing-harness</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.shared</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-verifier</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <author>false</author>
                    <doctitle>Liquibase Maven Plugin ${project.version} API</doctitle>
                    <quiet>true</quiet>
                    <doclint>none</doclint>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <jarOutputDirectory>${project.basedir}/target</jarOutputDirectory>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jar-javadoc</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-plugin-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generated-helpmojo</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>helpmojo</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <mojoDependencies>
                        <param>org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin</param>
                    </mojoDependencies>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>flatten-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <updatePomFile>true</updatePomFile>
                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/flattened-pom</outputDirectory>
                    <flattenedPomFilename>release.pom.xml</flattenedPomFilename>
                    <pomElements>
                        <profiles>remove</profiles>
                        <organization/>
                        <issueManagement/>
                    </pomElements>
                    <flattenMode>ossrh</flattenMode>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>flatten</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>flatten</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>flatten.clean</id>
                        <phase>clean</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>clean</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <!-- Converts the generated flattened-pom into a cleaner version for maven distribution -->
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>xml-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>transform-deploy-pom</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>transform</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <forceCreation>true</forceCreation>
                    <transformationSets>
                        <transformationSet>
                            <dir>${project.build.directory}/flattened-pom</dir>
                            <includes>release.pom.xml</includes>
                            <outputDir>${project.build.directory}</outputDir>
                            <stylesheet>${project.basedir}/src/main/maven/liquibase-deployment-pom.xslt</stylesheet>
                        </transformationSet>
                    </transformationSets>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                    <file>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${version}.jar</file>
                    <sources>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${version}-sources.jar</sources>
                    <javadoc>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${version}-javadoc.jar</javadoc>
                    <pomFile>${project.build.directory}/release.pom.xml</pomFile>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>custom-install</id>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-file</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.snyk</groupId>
                <artifactId>snyk-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>false</skip>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>

    </build>

    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-plugin-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>gpg-sign</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>env.GPG_PASSPHRASE</name>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-gpg-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.6</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <passphrase>${env.GPG_PASSPHRASE}</passphrase>
                            <gpgArguments>
                                <arg>--batch</arg>
                                <arg>--no-tty</arg>
                                <!-- This is necessary for gpg to not try to use the pinentry programs -->
                                <arg>--pinentry-mode</arg>
                                <arg>loopback</arg>
                            </gpgArguments>

                            <skip>false</skip>
                            <repositoryId>${deploy.repositoryId}</repositoryId>
                            <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                            <version>${liquibase.version}</version>
                            <url>${deploy.url}</url>
                            <file>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${liquibase.version}.jar</file>
                            <sources>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${version}-sources.jar</sources>
                            <javadoc>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${version}-javadoc.jar</javadoc>
                            <pomFile>${project.build.directory}/release.pom.xml</pomFile>
                        </configuration>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>custom-deploy</id>
                                <phase>deploy</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>sign-and-deploy-file</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Since this is liquibase source code shouldn't the files already be there?
Also even though I didn't change anything in the source code, IntelliJ says that the pom file as errors(could this be a problem in the source code?)
What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

Can you add this block into pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
    <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

and run command as shown below

```
> mvn clean install
```

finally, you should click *reload project* via maven tab

Comment: I already have liquibase-maven-plugin as a dependency in the pom file. Also, even though I didn't change anything ,IntelliJ is saying that there are errrors in the pom file(I will edit my question with the pom file)

Comment: Also in what pom? There are lots of them

Answer (score 0):

The version of the liquibase the Maven is complaining about is `4.3.2-local-SNAPSHOT`. `-SNAPSHOT` part here is suggesting that you are trying to use a version of the liquibase which is not released. Therefore you have to run the local build for the missing modules `org.liquibase:liquibase-core`.

Another approach would be to change the version of the parent to the released version, for example:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
    <artifactId>liquibase-base-module</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.2</version>
    <relativePath>../base-module.pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>
```

In this case, your local `liquibase-maven-plugin` depends on the released version of the `liquibase-base-module` and `liquibase-core`, which are resolved from the public repositories.

Comment: I did run liquibase-core compile

Comment: So it is suposed to change the property by a value in the version?